# How $c^{\aleph_0}=c$

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

I am reading about coutabaility, uncountability and cardinal numbers. I have attached herewith a screenshot of the wikipedia page.

I am not able to understand how in the third equation we show that $c^{\aleph_0}=c$

I know $c=2^{\aleph_0}$

Can some one please explain it? Rest of the equations are clear to me.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

p.s.: Source page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only a list of results you *can show*, and not the actual proof.  Once you have $c^{\aleph_0}=c$ the other equalities follows.

To show $c^{\aleph_0}=c$, we use the rule $(\kappa^\lambda)^\mu=\kappa^{\lambda\times\mu}$ and obtain
$$c^{\aleph_0}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\times\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=c$$

Comment: sorry but I know this. I wanted to understand the steps on the wikipedia page. Can you please add something on that. I mean why $c^{\aleph_0}=(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_0}=n^{\aleph_0}.......$" Thanks

Comment: It is easy to see you have $\geq$ in place of every $=$ on that line, and with a final $c\geq c^{\aleph_0}$ you can change all $\geq$ into $=$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.